# my database is too big and website pages crashed in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crash

i have 6825 invoices in my data base and i am almost fetching 6000 records by 6 ids and then my application crashes and i get this error
"is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"
here is my fetching query

```
$ids = [
  0 => 4
  1 => 220
  2 => 249
  3 => 533
  4 => 577
  5 => 578
]
$invoices = Invoice::whereIn('user_id', $ids)->get();
```

**how i can get all the record without getting crash application?**

Comment: First you need to check your server error log and find the specific error message. That's not a large amount of records btw. Although perhaps more than anyone needs to see on screen at once. Have you considered trying to use pagination?

Comment: Hello, if you need to view a large number of invoices you may want to paginate your data in the application. You may also want to monitor the memory usage for big queries and consider selecting the data you require rather than all of the data.

Check your error log or [enable ignition](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#configuration) for a more verbose error message that will allow you to understand why your application is crashing.

Comment: ADyson there is no error in error_log file but i think pagination is the solution and @KIKOSoftware u r write but i just showed arry ussing dd($ids); and then i copy paste it

Comment: what are you intending to do with all these records, btw?

Comment: in my blade i shows sum('subtotal') etc if if get 15 records i have only sum of 15 if i use  Invoice::whereIn('user_id', $ids)->paginate(20); it shows only 20 entries and it only show 20 record i dont know how i can get all these 6 ids record and devide by pages(10 record per page) then show option on my like (pag1 , page 2) by defult alomost i can get 4000 record my blade automaticly devide 10 record per page

Answer (score 0):

It is not best practice to get thousand of records at a time to fetch from db. So you use pagination and then fetch pagewise data which is faster and non-blocking.

Comment: If you actually look at the code in the question, the OP is getting 6 record groups NOT 1000's

Comment: i have total 6825 records and i am almost fetching 6000 records by 6 ids

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query directly in front of the database.
It may just take him a while to get an answer back.

Use explain to see which indexes the database uses.